# async/await __generator is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, typescript2.0, webpack-2

I am trying to use **async/await** functions with [angular2-webpack-starer](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) and [typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#downlevel-async-functions) (which now have support for this functions targeting es5), but I'm getting error:
[image]

This is code inside component:

```
// function inside component
async checkSlug(slug: string) {
       // nothing here
}
```

I am using webpack2.2 and typescript 2.1.5. This is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
    },
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es7",
      "es2015.promise"
    ],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "jasmine",
      "node",
      "protractor",
      "selenium-webdriver",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack",
      "chai",
      "chai-as-promised",
      "lodash"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

Comment: You've told the compiler not to generate that helper function for you with `"noEmitHelpers": true`. If you set that to false it should work. Otherwise you need to provide the helper function. See https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/12/16/typescript-2-1-external-helpers-library

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this tsconfig.json works

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
    },
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es7",
      "es5",
      "es2015.promise"
    ],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "jasmine",
      "node",
      "protractor",
      "selenium-webdriver",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack",
      "chai",
      "chai-as-promised",
      "lodash"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

Comment: This answer is clearer about the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42426996/1569600

`noEmitHelpers: false`