# __awaiter is not defined when using async/await in Typescript

Tags: asynchronous, typescript, async-await

I have the following code snippet in Typescript:

```
nsp.on('connection', async function (socket) {
    await this.emitInitialPackage(nsp, currentLine, currentCell);
}

emitInitialPackage(nsp: any, name: string, cell: any) {
    return db.Line.find({
        where: {
            name: name,
            CellId: cell
        }
    }).then(results => {
        nsp.emit('value', results);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

However, when this is compiled (v2.2.1) and run, I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: __awaiter is not defined

What does this mean and how do I get the expected functionality?

## Update:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015.promise", 
      "es5"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node", 
      "express"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you share your `tsconfig.json` ? And the command you use to compile your code.

Comment: @Romain Sure - [here](https://gist.github.com/georgeedwards/755fd6a6561a245bac55bf51b8493a51) is the tsconfig, I run this with just `tsc -w` from the directory with that tsconfig in it's root.

Comment: If the posted answer resolves your problem, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you use some functionalities from future version of JavaScript (ES6 and beyond) like in your case `async/await`, `TypeScript` generates helper functions. These helper functions are used to provide the new functionalities as ES5 code, thus it can be run in a web browser.

## Your problem:

In your `tsconfig.json` you set the `noEmitHelpers` value to `true`. By doing that you tell the `TypeScript` compiler that you will provide these helper functions yourself.

## How to fix it:

- You can set the `noEmitHelpers` value to `false` in your `tsconfig.json`, thus the `TypeScript` compiler will emit the helper functions when needed. One drawback of this method is that if you use for example `async/await` in 2 different files, the helper functions will be emitted 2 times (one per file).
- The other solution is to set the `--importHelpers` flag when you use `tsc`. It will tell the `TypeScript` compiler to include the helper functions only once. Please note that if you use this solution you have to install the `tslib` package.

In your case: `tsc --importHelpers -w`

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer didn't work in my case, but I found that my `tsconfig.json` was targeting `es6` (`"target":"es6"`).

What this means is that TypeScript transpiles to code that uses the `__awaiter` util because `async` `await` was [not included in the spec until ES2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995484/whats-the-purpose-of-typescripts-awaiter).

I fixed this by changing my `target` to `ESNext` (or anything `ES2017` and above)