# Whats the purpose of typescript's __awaiter

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

consider this simple class

```
class Test {
    private foo(): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve();
        });
    }

    private async bar() {
        await this.foo();
    }
}
```

This get compiled into

```
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator.throw(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(result.value); }).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments)).next());
    });
};
class Test {
    foo() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve();
        });
    }
    bar() {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
            yield this.foo();
        });
    }
}
//# sourceMappingURL=Test.js.map
```

but ES6 supports the keyword await natively, why would typescript get rid of await and return another Promise wrapper?

Whats the purpose of __awaiter

Comment: are you compiling to ES6 as target? Or es5?

Comment: @toskv ES6, ES5 wont compile

Comment: @Steve sure it will.

Comment: @AluanHaddad "Build:Async functions are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6 and higher." is what I got when I tried ES5

Comment: Then your version of TypeScript is roughly a year old.

Comment: @AluanHaddad gonna get the latest version of TS and try this out. you got me curious how TS can handle this in ES5

Comment: @Steve go for it! You will find `__generator` to be of interest just as  you do `__awaiter` :)

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have target set to `es2018` but I still see __awaiter in the output. Any idea why? (wish it'd go away!)

Comment: @AluanHaddad Ah, it was because I was importing a tsconfig.json with a single `extends` option in it, and passing the non-existent `compilerOptions` field to ts-node's `compilerOptions` option. Switching to instead using ts-node's `project` option worked.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Typescript includes the `__awaiter` helper because `async`/`await` is *not* a part of the `es6`/`es2015` specification.

> Initial definition in ES2017. -- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

If you don't want to include this helper, you need to target `es2017`.

Comment: dam. shoulda looked more closely. Was assuming promise + async/await comes together