# Angular 2 - __generator is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to intercept outgoing HTTP requests in Angular 2 and trying to generate a token by passing in the *request body* as a parameter in my custom function and then trying to attach the generated token to the header of each post request. I have attached the code snippet below.

I was getting this runtime error: `"e.json() is not a function"`

So, I instead tried catching the error and add 'json' function to error if it's missing and now I'm getting this runtime error:

`"message: __generator is not defined"` `stack: "ReferenceError: __generator is not defined↵    at e.<anonymous>"`

I have set `"noEmitHelpers": false` as it was a solution described in this question: [async/await __generator is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830118/async-await-generator-is-not-defined)

But, the runtime error still persists.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
declare var TextEncoder: any

import { Headers, Http, Request, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, XHRBackend } from "@angular/http"

import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"

import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx"

// operators

import "rxjs/add/operator/catch"

import "rxjs/add/observable/throw"

import "rxjs/add/operator/map"

import { fromPromise } from "rxjs/observable/fromPromise"

import { switchMap } from "rxjs/operators"

@Injectable()

export class DigestIntegrationInterceptor extends Http {    

    constructor(
        backend: XHRBackend,
        options: RequestOptions
    ) {
        super(backend, options)
    }
    
    
    request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return super.request(url, options);
    }                   

    post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {                
        const timeStamp = new Date().getTime() + "";
        const tokenPromise = this.generateDigestHex(this.generateToken(body, timeStamp));                
        return fromPromise(tokenPromise).pipe(
            switchMap((token:string) => super.post(url, body, this.generateHeaders(token, timeStamp, options))),
            
            // add 'json' function to error if it's missing
            catchError(e => typeof e.json === 'function' ? Observable.throw(e): Observable.throw({ json: () => e })),
      
            // To check what the observable emits - for debugging purpose only
            tap({
               next: v => console.log('http interceptor next', v),
               error: e => console.log('http interceptor error', e),
            })
        );                
    }                         

    generateHeaders(token:string, timeStamp, options: RequestOptionsArgs){        
        if (options == null) {
            options = new RequestOptions();
        }
        if (options.headers == null) {
            options.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        }
        options.headers.append("X-TOKEN", token);
        options.headers.append("X-REQ-TS", timeStamp);

        return options;
    }

    generateToken(requestBody: any, timeStamp: string): string {
        return `X-${timeStamp}-${JSON.stringify(requestBody)}`;
    }    

    async generateDigestHex(message) {
        const msgUint8 = new TextEncoder().encode(message); 
        const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", msgUint8); 
        const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)); 
        const hashHex = hashArray
          .map((b) => b.toString(16)['padStart'](2, "0"))
          .join(""); 
        return hashHex;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: hard to tell. "e.json()" is not part of the code you shared. maybe start commenting out code until you find the exact line that is triggering the error?

Comment: Usually the compiler says at which line the code fails. That information makes it much easier to find the actual problem. Also it would make it easier if you remove all unnecessary code for this issue

Comment: I'd guess though, that `const token:string = fromPromise(tokenPromise).pipe(switchMap((token:string) => token));` is the problem. `fromPromise` returns an Observable, but you declare a string type

Comment: @Rick, thanks for your input. But, that error was getting triggered in another component, so I have instead updated my approach for the above code.

Comment: @A_A, yes that's the problem. I want to store the token as a string, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You can't convert from Observable<string> to string. The observable is asynchronous, ie it possibly needs some time until it is finished. I'm no expert on Angular, but I think [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) should work for you (merging the token generation with the post request).

Comment: Change your post method to async, and `const token:string = await fromPromise(...)`. It should wait to the promise result instead of returning it.

Comment: Yes @Morphyish, but in doing so, the post method would be returning a promise, as opposed to the http post method's required return type i.e ```Observable<Response>```

Comment: Ah gotcha. Then @fridoo answer looks like the best approach.

Comment: You should post new questions instead of constantly changing your question. Otherwise this question will end up with answers that are not relevant to the current state of the question (as is already the case). New questions also get more immediate attention than older ones. If a question you posted isn't relevant to you anymore and has no helpful answers with upvotes you might also consider deleting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to your post request after you get the token from `fromPromise(tokenPromise)`.

```ts
return fromPromise(tokenPromise).pipe(
  // add 'json' function to error
  catchError(e => throwError({ json: () => Promise.resolve(e) })),
  switchMap((token:string) => 
    super.post(url, body, this.generateHeaders(token, timeStamp, options))
  ),
  
  // check what your observable emits - for debugging purpose only
  tap({
    next: v => console.log('http interceptor next', v),
    error: e => console.log('http interceptor error', e),
  })
);
```

Comment: Yes @fridoo, I tried the above approach earlier, but it triggered a runtime error in another component. So, had to change my approach.

Comment: ```e.json() is not a function``` is the runtime error

Comment: @overflow-x I think the observable you return sends an error `e` and your component expects that this error has the function `json()`. Errors send by `super.post` might have this function (I'm not sure) but what if your promise rejects? If the promise rejects the observable `fromPromise(tokenPromise)` will send an error. This error probably won't have a `json` function. So you could check if an error has a json function and add it if it's missing. In the long run though you should move the observable error handling from components and into services to centralise it.

Comment: fridoo, I tried your new approach, and this is the error message that's getting displayed now: ```__generator is not defined```  ```stack: ReferenceError: __generator is not defined↵    at e.<anonymous> ```  I tried setting ```noEmitHelpers": false``` as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830118/async-await-generator-is-not-defined.   But the error still persists.

Comment: @overflow-x Try to wrap the error returned in `json` with a Promise: `Promise.resolve(e)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can't access observable values the way you have here... you need to do it more like:

```
post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {                
    const timeStamp = new Date().getTime() + "";
    const tokenPromise = this.generateDigestHex(this.generateToken(body, timeStamp));                
    return fromPromise(tokenPromise).pipe(switchMap((token:string) => {
      return super.post(url, body, this.generateHeaders(token, timeStamp, options));  
    }));          
}
```

you switch off the first promise into the post once you have the token value.

Comment: thanks, @bryan60, I am using this approach, but when I try to load the app, it throws a runtime error: "e.json() is not a function".